# How do i convert reader.result into string?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-forms

When I try to upload an image on angular three is an error on reader.result in bellow typescript file how can I fix this?
I added `console.log(image)` in the function which is onImagePicked it also not shown in console why doesn't it show in the console?

typescript file

```
     imagePreview:string;


ngOnInit(){
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    title : new FormControl(null,{validators:[Validators.required]}),
    content: new FormControl(null,{validators:[Validators.required]} ),
    image: new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
  });


        onImagePicked(event: Event){
          const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
          this.form.patchValue({image: file});
          this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
          console.log(file);
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = () => {
            this.imagePreview = reader.result;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
```

Html file

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onAddPost()"  *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="title" placeholder="title"  >
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('title').invalid" >Please enter the Title</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput rows="6" formControlName="content" placeholder="caption"   ></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('content').invalid" >Please enter the Content</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
<div class='image-preview'>
  <img src="" [alt]="form.value.title">
</div>


    <div>
        <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="filePicker.click()">Add Image</button>
        <input type="file" #filePicker (chnage)="onImagePicked($event)">
      </div>

    <button  mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Save Post</button>
</form>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: What is your question? You are trying to convert `imagePreview` into string?

Comment: I can not assign reader.result  to imagePreview which is string type , there is type error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation for [FileReader.result()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result), the type of the return value for that method might be of `string`, or `ArrayBuffer`.

You might need use TypeScript's [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to tell the compiler that `reader.result` is of type `string`, since you have set the type for `imagePreview` as `string`.

```
reader.onload = () => {
  this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could equally set in the type for imagePreview as `imagePreview: string | ArrayBuffer` when declaring it.

Or you can as well do:

```
reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = <string>reader.result;
    }
```